# Black textures on unity-iPhone on iOS only

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, 3d

When I launch my game in Unity Editor the Texture2D displays the image correctly whatever it is a PNG or JPG file. The same in Android Builed ask running on a smartphone. But when I build my unity 2019.2.4f1 project on iPhone, it does bug. When I try to load a Texture2D with a PNG file it displays it correctly but when it is a JPG file, it displays me a black texture instead of the actual texture. What should I do for the iOS export to make it work?
[image: Build setting 1]
[image: Build Setting 2]
[image: Black texture is for iOS]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all textures have override for IOS unchecked in Import Settings:

[image]